# How to get notification in Azure in case total runtime is more for a new build

Tags: scala, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, gatling

I have pipeline in Azure DevOps, in which Gatling loading test scenario executes every night. How can I get notification in Azure (and on e-mail also) in case total runtime in last time is more than in previous time (e.g. 31.03.2020 total runtime was 10 min, 01.04.2020 total runtime was 12 min - in this case i want to get notification)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a new build pipeline which only is triggered by the [Build Completion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/pipeline-triggers?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic) of your test pipeline.

And add a script task to call [Build rest api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) to this new pipeline to calculate the total runtime of the builds. And add a [Send email task](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rvo.SendEmailTask&targetId=47097972-e633-4284-ad72-fe49f3c8dd5f) to send you email on the condition of duration time is greater than the previous build. The detailed steps is listed as below.

1, Setup a new pipeline and configure the Build Completion trigger

Go to **Get sources** --> Check **Don't sync sources** to skip checkout sources
[image]

Click **Agent job**--> Check **Allow scripts to access the OAuth token** to allow scripts to call rest api
[image]

Go to **Triggers** tab--> **Build completion**--> Click **Add** to select your test pipeline as **Trigggering build**

By setting up the Build completion Triggering build, this new pipeline will be triggered when your test pipeline is complete.

[image]

2, Add a script task to call Build rest api and calculate the duration time. And [store the result to a variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#set-variables-in-scripts). Check below powershell script:

```
$url = "$(System.TeamFoundationCollectionUri)$(System.TeamProject)/_apis/build/builds/$(Build.TriggeredBy.BuildId)?api-version=5.1"
echo $url

$result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{authorization = "Bearer $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN"} -ContentType "application/json" -Method get

# calculate the totaltime of the newest build
$time = [datetime]$result.finishTime - [datetime]$result.startTime

$thisBuild= $time.TotalMinutes

# get the last build
$lasturl = "$(System.TeamFoundationCollectionUri)$(System.TeamProject)/_apis/build/builds?definitions=$(Build.TriggeredBy.DefinitionId)&resultFilter=succeeded&`$top=2&api-version=5.1"

$lastResult =Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $lasturl -Headers @{authorization = "Bearer $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN"} -ContentType "application/json" -Method get

#Caculate the totaltime of the last build
$lasttime = [datetime]$lastResult.value[1].finishTime - [datetime]$lastResult.value[1].startTime
$lastBuild = $lasttime.TotalMinutes

#Store the result to varialbe  isLonger    
if($thisBuild -ge $lastBuild ){ echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=isLonger]True" }
```

3, Add Send email task to send out the email. And set a custom condtion to `eq(variables.isLonger, 'True')`. So that this task will only be executed when the total time is greater.

[image]

Hope above helps!

Comment: Thanks for such detailed answer, Levi Lu-MSFT! Could you clarify - can I use the presented PowerShell script as it shown above or will it need to change something for my task? (I'm new to PowerShell)

Comment: I make it generic. You can use it directly, no need to change anything.

Comment: could you answer - how can i use default notifications (it exist in project settings in Azure DevOps) instead of "Send Email" task after completing the step "Build rest api and calculate the duration time"?

Comment: i am afraid you cannot use the default notification directly in the pipeline. The workaround is to replace the send Email task with a script task to fail the pipeline if the total runtime is greater(eg. `if($(isLonger) -eq "True"){  exit 1 }`). And then add a build fail notification to send you notifications on the failure of the pipeline.

Comment: Thank you, Levi Lu-MSFT! Your advice is very helpful!